# How to find the function $Y(K,L)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$\alpha$ is just a constant and it's given that

$$\frac{\partial Y(K,L)}{\partial K}=\alpha\frac{Y}{K}$$
$$\frac{\partial Y(K,L)}{\partial L}=(1-\alpha)\frac{Y}{L}$$

Doing some integration

$$\ln(Y)=\alpha \ln(K)+C_1$$
$$\ln(Y)=(1-\alpha) \ln(L)+C_2$$

Then

$$Y=C_3K^\alpha $$
$$Y=C_4L^{1-\alpha} $$

Since $Y$ is proportional to $K^\alpha$ and to $L^{1-\alpha}$ when the other variable is held constant, I'm very tempted to say  that it's proportional to both, making

$$Y(K,L)=A K^\alpha L^{1-\alpha}$$

However, I couldn't find a way to prove that that's actually true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $C_3$ should depend on $L$ and $C_4$ on $K$, namely
$$ Y=C_3(L)K^\alpha $$
and
$$ Y=C_4(K)L^{1-\alpha}. $$
So
$$ C_3(L)K^\alpha=C_4(K)L^{1-\alpha} $$
or
$$ \frac{C_3(L)}{L^{1-\alpha}}=\frac{C_4(K)}{K^\alpha}\equiv A.$$
From this, one has
$$ C_3(L)=AL^{1-\alpha},C_4(k)=AK^\alpha$$
and hence
$$ Y=AL^{1-\alpha}K^\alpha. $$

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes a lot of sense to introduce the $C_3$ and $C_4$ as a function of $L$ and $K$. However, I don't think I understand how you introduced $A$ in the fourth line.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it now xD